# Census- Records column 30

Tags: census-records, minnesota

Ancestor was born in 1832 England, lived in Minneapolis Ward 13. Column 30 ..what is the meaning of
-9- .  No letters just  dash 9 dash

Comment: What year was the census that you are asking about?

Comment: Could you attach a link to an copy of the original?

Comment: If its the 1910 census the answer may be [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3257/5200).